# Azure AD B2C - Customize Email verification in separate steps

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are using Azure AD B2C with Custom Policies. We noticed that Email-verification on Signup is pretty hard to do for the majority of users from a usability perspective. Hence, we would like to implement the following flow:

Step 1: Provide user data (Email, First Name, Last Name, Paswword + Confirm Password) and user can click next

Step 2: User sees a text that an email was send to him with a verification code. User should have the capability:

- to enter the code and continue or
- resend the code

On clicking continue, the user is redirected to the target app if code is correct.

Is this flow possible? If yes, can someone give a concrete example on how it needs to be setup as custom policy?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

There is a sample here that demonstrates the concepts you are looking for
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/split-email-verification-and-signup

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I did not expect a response so soon and even with sample policies. I will check it out and answer soon.

Comment: I investigated your sample and implemented it for now because it is better than the default flow. Do you think the flow described above is doable? It is a very famous flow I think.

Comment: Absolutely possible to achieve. The second part to send a text would need a custom REST API to be called. Finally present the second page which performs Email OTP verification, fire off an initial code by using JS to hit the “send code” button.